# sqlachemy, says decimal is not defined?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Trying to make a column of type decimal:

```
Column('cost', DECIMAL)
```

Erorr, name 'DECIMAL' is not defined.

SqlAlch seems to support decimal, am I missing an import?

BTW, how do I also create a longtext column?

I'm using mysql.

Comment: Don't you usually specify the precision for a DECIMAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
import sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL as DECIMAL
```

Comment: For these how this doesn't work, try `from sqlalchemy.types import DECIMAL`